# JQgrid: how to construct the table, retrieving specific info from a DB with a PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I've not such big skills for programming and I'm struggling with this part that probably is not a big deal. I need to generate a table with specific information from the selected customer account, retrieving it from an MS SQL DB, having the option to edit each row and cell.

I'm using jqgrid to generate the grid, and add the inline edit options with action buttons. Everything works great if I define specifically the query in the server-side php call to the DB, but the thing is that I need to populate the grid with the information related to the specific account. As I get to this screen after entering a login page and a validation page before, I already have the php variable with the customer's number, and I need to pass that one to jqgrid so I can be able to retrieve only the information that relates to that account.

Here is what is working, first the page where my customer's account info is being showed:

```
#customerinfo.php
<?php
   $acctnum = $_SESSION['custnum'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ 
    $("#regphones").jqGrid({
    url:'custregphone.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['Actions','Autodialer ID','Customer #','Access #','Destination #','Description'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'act', index:'act', width:70, sortable:false},
      {name:'autodialer_id', index:'autodialer_id', width:80, align:'center', sortable:true, editable:true, hidden:true},
      {name:'account', index:'account', width:90, align:'center', sortable:true, editable:true, hidden:true}, 
      {name:'dnis', index:'dnis', width:90, align:'center', sortable:true, editable:true}, 
      {name:'destination', index:'destination', width:120, align:'center', sortable:true, editable:true}, 
      {name:'description', index:'description', width:120, align:'center', sortable:true, editable:true}            
    ],
    pager: '#regphonesp',
    rowNum:5,
    rowList:[5,10,15],
    sortname: 'dnis',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: false,
    gridview: true,
    scrollOffset:0,
    gridComplete: function(){
      var ids = jQuery("#regphones").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
        for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ 
            var cl = ids[i]; 
            be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#regphones').editRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#regphones').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#regphones').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            jQuery("#regphones").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
        }
      },
    editurl: "custregphone_edit.php",
    caption: 'Registered Phones',
      }); 
      jQuery("#regphones").jqGrid('navGrid',"#regphonesp",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
  });
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  Registered Numbers: <?php echo $acctnum; ?>
  <table id="regphones"></table> 
  <div id="regphonesp"></div>
  ...
</body>
```

Then the custregphone.php:

```
<?php
include("functions_engtst.php");

$page = $_POST['page'];
$limit = $_POST['rows']; 
$sidx = $_POST['sidx'];
$sord = $_POST['sord']; 
$acctnum = $_POST['acctnum'];

if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 

$dbh = get_db("live");
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM REGPHONE WHERE ACCOUNT='3058318318'");
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
    $total_pages = 0; 
}
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT autodialer_id,account,dnis,destination,description FROM REGPHONE WHERE ACCOUNT= '3058318318' ORDER BY $sidx $sord");
$sth->execute();

$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages; 
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    $responce->rows[$i]['autodialer_id']=$row[autodialer_id]; 
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array("",$row[autodialer_id],$row[account],$row[dnis],$row[destination],$row[description]);
    $i++; 
} 
echo json_encode($responce);
?>
```

This code works, but the issue is that I cannot dynamically get the information of the account, I had to specify it in the queries. My question is how can I pass the variable *$acctnum* to the two queries in the custregphone.php to get something like this:

```
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM REGPHONE WHERE ACCOUNT= $acctnum");
    $sth->execute();

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT autodialer_id,account,dnis,destination,description FROM REGPHONE WHERE ACCOUNT= $acctnum ORDER BY $sidx $sord");
    $sth->execute()
```

Comment: I think the simplest way to do it was ussing the `$_SESSION` that I already had defined. Anyway, if anyone has a recommendation for this please let me know. Thanks!